# Regex to get value after colon and disregard the square bracket or angle bracket

Tags: regex, expression

I tried googling and but couldn't find what I want. Tried a few workaround in the regex tester but to no avail.

I wanted to get the value after the colon but don't include the square bracket or angle bracket that is with it.

So meaning based on the following examples:

```
userId: user1
userId: <user1>
userId: <user 1>
[userId: <user1>]
```

I should only get the value `user1`

I tried this regex: `userId:\s(.*?])` but it will get the `<>` and `]` after user1.

By the way, I am using Ruby Regular Expression Editor if it helps any way.

***Updates:*** Needs to work with words that have spacing in between.

Comment: If user name can have more than word chars, use `userId:\s*([^\]>]*)`

Comment: Just a bit more! It included the left angle bracket though. But I already got the answer. But appreciate your help a lot! (:

Comment: Yours matched them, too, but you did not mention that in your question.

Comment: haha I did!

*
I wanted to get the value after the colon but don't include the square bracket or angle bracket that is with it.
*
And I show what value I wanted to get in the end!

Comment: Yeah, but when describing your regex behavior, you did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
userId:\W*([\w ]+)
```

See [Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/EB4aCV/1)

Comment: This works amazing. But I realized that I have words with spacing as well. So need to match that also. So sorry my bad, just included that in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/(:\s<?)(\w+\s?\d)/g` and then match the second group:

```
var myString = "[userId: <user1>]";
var myRegexp = /(:\s<?)(\w+\s?\d)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[2]); // user1
```

Note that `"userId: <user 1>"` will return `"user 1"`